# A problem with a query

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I would like to include dname, deptno, loc, add up ename and label the colum as Number_of_People sum up salary lable the colum Total Salary then join the dept table and I only want to do it for dept 30

Heres the error I get

```
SQL> select dname,deptno, loc, count(ename) as Number_of_People, sum(sal) as   Total_Salary from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno group by dname,loc where  deptno =30;
 select dname,deptno, loc, count(ename) as Number_of_People, sum(sal) as Total_Salary from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno group by dname,loc where deptno =30

                                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


SQL>
```

Table emp;

```
 SQL> select empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate,comm, deptno from emp;

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        COMM     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81                    10
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81                    30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81                    10
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81                    20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1400         30
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81        300         30
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81          0         30
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81                    30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81        500         30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81                    20
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80                    20

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        COMM     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09-DEC-82                    20
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12-JAN-83                    20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82                    10

  14 rows selected.
```

Table dept;

```
  SQL> select * from dept;

  DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
  ---------- -------------- -------------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `where` clause to come before the `group by` clause.

Try:

```
select dname,deptno, loc
, count(ename) as Number_of_People
, sum(sal) as   Total_Salary 
from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno 
where deptno=30
group by dname,loc;
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the way you have it. ERROR at line 1: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined –

Comment: In that case, one of `dname`, `deptno`, or `loc` is defined in both `emp` and `dept`.  Choose which one you want (eg if it's `dname` that's repeated, choose whether you want `emp.dname` or `dept.dname`).

Comment: All you need to change is to put emp.deptno in the select instead of just deptno. Since it is defined in both, it needs to know which table to pull it from.

Comment: SQL> select dname,deptno, loc , count(ename) as Number_of_People , sum(sal) as   Total_Salary
  from emp join dept on dept.dname = emp.dname  where deptno=30 group by dname,loc;

Comment: If that's the query that you entered, then you did not "try that".  Change `deptno` to `emp.deptno` in the first place where `deptno` occurs in the query.

Comment: SQL> select dname,emp.deptno, loc , count(ename) as Number_of_People , sum(sal) as   Total_Sa
lary  from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno  where emp.deptno=30 group by dname,loc;

select dname,emp.deptno, loc , count(ename) as Number_of_People , sum(sal) as   Total_Salary
 from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno  where emp.deptno=30 group by dname,loc
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression


SQL>

Comment: That would probably be because you're copying the same query twice.  Take a moment.  Breathe.  Think about what you're doing.

Comment: @user770022 - you have to have all non-aggregated columns in the group by clause; so you need to add emp.deptno there too. (@Jack, I think that's just formatting ,the 'repeat' is the query being echoed back to hilight the error? +1 for breathing though)

Answer (score 3):

`Where` clauses must come before `group by` clauses.  If you need to do filtering after the grouping, use `having`

```
select dname, emp.deptno as deptno, loc, count(ename) as Number_of_People, 
    sum(sal) as   Total_Salary from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno 
    where  emp.deptno =30
    group by dname,loc ;
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the way you have it. ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: yeah.  you have two deptno columns.  Even though they're both the same value (per your join condition), you have to tell SQL which one you want returned.  I edited the statement.

Comment: Are there any other columns you are selecting that might be in both tables?  It's funny that the first google result for that error returns an example using tables named "emp" and "dept".

Comment: Found it.  It's "deptno" in your where clause.

Comment: SQL> select dname,deptno, loc , count(ename) as Number_of_People , sum(sal) as   Total_Salary
  from emp join dept on dept.dname = emp.dname  where deptno=30 group by dname,loc;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3471/discussion-between-carl-f-and-user770022)